# Easy way to pdf a web report

Tags: flash, pdf, reporting-services, reporting

We are trying to create a web reporting system, with the standard flash chart's, one of the major requirements is that this report must be emailed to customers on a regular schedule as a PDF file.

Does anyone know of either

- An easy tool to point at the webpage and pdf it, including flash charts
- Another way of doing this?

We have tried sql server reporting in the past and found it to be a little slow and generally the charting is a little unpretty.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your web reporting system is being built using .NET you may want to look into ABCpdf Component for .NET which can be found [here](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm). I am not sure if it works with flash charts, as at my work we use charts that are images, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

What is your envirnment like?  You could try using itext or itextsharp to build PDF files.  Crystal Reports is another option, but maintaining separate report files could be a pain in the ass.

Comment: itextsharp is great, although I don't think it can take a snapshot of an existing page.

Comment: I'm sure it can't, but depending on what you are generating, it might be as easy as using the same back-end code to generate the report in a different format.  It really depends on how the application is designed.